# Error packaging Electron Forge application: Failed to locate module "client-only"

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-forge

I am developing an Electron React application using Electron Forge. The application builds and runs successfully, but when I try to package it using electron-forge make, I encounter the following error:

```
 This normally means that either you have deleted this package already somehow (check your ignore settings if using electron-packager).  Or your module installation failed.
at Walker.<anonymous> (/Users/danuja/Desktop/my-new-app/node_modules/.pnpm/flora-colossus@1.0.1/node_modules/flora-colossus/lib/Walker.js:110:35)
    at step (/Users/danuja/Desktop/my-new-app/node_modules/.pnpm/flora-colossus@1.0.1/node_modules/flora-colossus/lib/Walker.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/danuja/Desktop/my-new-app/node_modules/.pnpm/flora-colossus@1.0.1/node_modules/flora-colossus/lib/Walker.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/danuja/Desktop/my-new-app/node_modules/.pnpm/flora-colossus@1.0.1/node_modules/flora-colossus/lib/Walker.js:4:58)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have already verified that the @headlessui/react package is present in my node_modules directory. I have also tried reinstalling the dependencies and deleting the node_modules directory to perform a fresh installation, but no luck! Application works fine on development as well.

I suspect there might be an issue with the packaging process or a compatibility problem between Electron Forge and the @headlessui/react package. Has anyone encountered a similar error while packaging an Electron React application? How can I resolve this issue and successfully package my Electron Forge app?